# Since installing v. 16, computer won't wake up from display sleep

Tags: suspend

Running Ubuntu 16 on an old Dell P4 PC. Worked OK on v.14 but since installing 16 when the display sleeps I can't wake it up. Have to hard-reboot.

As requested, here's the output from uname -a: 
Linux DellDimension4600i 4.4.25-040425-generic #201610161231 SMP Sun Oct 16 16:48:18 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: When you say v16 are you talking about 16.04 or 16.10?

Comment: 16.04. (As a workaround, since I can ssh to the machine from another computer on the LAN, is there a terminal command that will wake up the GUI?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Found the solution on another forum. Please confirm if it works.
The problem is with two GPU's, Intel & nvidia. If nvdia is the default GPU, suspend and hibernate will have issues.

Step1 : Run "nvidia-settings" on terminal.

Step2 : In "PRIME Profiles" tab, select the GPU as "Intel" instead of "NVIDIA".

Step3 : Save and restart your machine.

Lemme know if this solution works in Ubuntu 16.0.4. I tried this on 14.0.4 and it worked.

Edit: The solution also works in Ubuntu 16.0.4. I upgraded my 14.0.4 to 16.0.4 and this issue didn't reappear.

Comment: When I first tried it, it said I had to first install it. Did that, and now when I run it I get this: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help`
       for usage information.  And the --help option isn't all that helpful

Comment: Do u have Nvidia graphics card in your system?? If not then this solution is not meant for you.

Comment: No, when I got it, it was apparently using Intel integrated graphics. I added a used ATI Radeon 9800 XT 256MB card. It seems to work fine, but ever since updating from Ubuntu 14 to 16, it won't wake up from sleep.

Comment: Then you should perhaps install the proprietary driver of ATI Radeon and then try for the settings there. My solution applies to Nvidia graphic card.

Comment: I believe I have installed the driver, though I don't know how to be sure. Seems like there should be an app for tweaking the card's settings, but I wouldn't know how to find it. The main Ubuntu hardware settings control panel is of no help. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: The solution works but it does not solve the overall issue that some people may need the graphics power.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302) in kernel 4.4.0. You can either wait for the official update, or install newer kernel which solved the bug.

## 32 Bit

Run following command on terminal to download kernel 4.4.8 on 32 bit machine :

```
cd /tmp
wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.25/linux-headers-4.4.25-040425_4.4.25-040425.201610161231_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.25/linux-headers-4.4.25-040425-generic_4.4.25-040425.201610161231_i386.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.25/linux-image-4.4.25-040425-generic_4.4.25-040425.201610161231_i386.deb
```

Install the downloaded kernel :

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4*.deb linux-image-4.4*.deb
```

## 64 Bit

Run following command on terminal to download kernel 4.4.8 on 64 bit machine

```
cd /tmp
wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.25/linux-headers-4.4.25-040425_4.4.25-040425.201610161231_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.25/linux-headers-4.4.25-040425-generic_4.4.25-040425.201610161231_amd64.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.25/linux-image-4.4.25-040425-generic_4.4.25-040425.201610161231_amd64.deb
```

Install the downloaded kernel :

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4*.deb linux-image-4.4*.deb
```

After installation is complete, update `grub` and reboot your computer. Choose your new kernel on grub.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Post output of `uname -a` on your question.

Comment: Per this bug report thread [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302) , LOTS of people are struggling with this.